# ABP account module change default URL

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

**ABP Framework version: 5.1.4**.

**User Interface: Angular**

**Your database provider: EF Core/Tired**

- Steps needed to **reproduce** the problem.

I'm running ABP tired angular project and I published it on IIS

[image]

```
HttpApi.Host as https://www.carsharing.com/ApiHost

IdentityServer as https://www.carsharing.com/IdentityServer 

Web.Public as https://www.carsharing.com/WebPublic
```

When I open My Account tab in IdentityServer or WebPublic to change the password or account-info the request goes to the wrong URL

```
https://www.carsharing.com/api/account/my-profile
```

[image]

it should be going to

```
https://www.carsharing.com/identityserver/api/account/my-profile
```

on angular its working fine
[image]

I had the same issue with swagger but I added

```cs
app.UseAbpSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
           options.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CarSharing API"); 
           options.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("baseUrl","/ApiHost/"); <--This line
        });
```

Is there any way to update the URL in account module?